# send json curl request from php with line breaks

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to convert CLI curl to php. I have tried this manually, I have tried using scripts, I have tried searching for solutions, I can't find anything useful relating to sending json curl requires containing line breaks using php.

```
curl -X POST "https://url.com" -H "accept: application/json" -H "X-API-Key: API_KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "description_key": "{\n\"inner_text_key1\": \"inner_text_value\"\n}" }'
```

So I have a curl that works from the CLI without problem that is similar to above. Note that the description contains a STRING that is formatted as if it were json. This is correct.

However whenever I try to add the line breaks in on php, the whole things breaks. The api I am working with ends up returning "unescaped characters" on the \n

How do I properly format in such a way that the line breaks are sent with the request and not interpreted as unescaped characters?

If I remove the line breaks from the request it will send perfectly. Equally doing so from the CLI works perfect, just can't get it to work with php AND the line breaks.

The problem is not really the php itself as stated, it works without the \n none the less the php is below.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://url.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\", \"description_key\": \"{\n\"inner_text_key1\": \"inner_text_value\"\n}\"}");
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'X-Api-Key: no';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I just tried `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CRLF, 1);` same result.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EGQByhFv

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything that had been suggested, and none of it worked. Not even encoding and decoding. In the end... the fix was simple.

Originally I had:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\", \"description_key\": \"{\n\"inner_text_key1\": \"inner_text_value\"\n}\"}");`

I merely changed that to

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "description_key": \"{\n\"inner_text_key1\": \"inner_text_value\"\n}"}');`

So I removed all the escapes on the " except the part of the inner json "description": area and used a single quote around the entire thing. Suddenly the line breaks work and all is submitted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like json encoded in json.

```
echo var_export(
    json_decode(
        '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "description_key": "{\n\"inner_text_key1\": \"inner_text_value\"\n}" }'
        , true
    ), true
);
// array(
//     'key1'            => 'value1',
//     'key2'            => 'value2',
//     'description_key' => '{
// "inner_text_key1": "inner_text_value"
// }',
// )
```

Json decoding `description_key` on the json decoded string works.
So you got a problem on the source of the string.

If you cannot change that then

- json decode the string
- json decode the `description_key` offset
- json encode the array again (once)
- use it on curl

---

**EDIT:**

Understood: json in array is expected. Line break is the problem.

Then you could just decode, encode:

```
    $jsonString = '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "description_key": "{\n\"inner_text_key1\": \"inner_text_value\"\n}" }';
    $array = json_decode($jsonString, true);
    // array (
    //     'key1' => 'value1',
    //     'key2' => 'value2',
    //     'description_key' => '{"inner_text_key1":"inner_text_value"}',
    // )
    if ($array['description_key']
        and is_string($array['description_key'])
    ) {
        $array['description_key'] = json_decode($array['description_key'], true);
        // array (
        //     'key1' => 'value1',
        //     'key2' => 'value2',
        //     'description_key' => array (
        //         'inner_text_key1' => 'inner_text_value',
        //     ),
        // )
        // If you NEED it to be encoded in encoded json then:
        $array['description_key'] = json_encode($array['description_key']);
        // array (
        //     'key1' => 'value1',
        //     'key2' => 'value2',
        //     'description_key' => '{"inner_text_key1":"inner_text_value"}',
        // )
    }
    $jsonString = json_encode($array);
    // '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","description_key":"{\\"inner_text_key1\\":\\"inner_text_value\\"}"}'
```

Comment: From the post:  "Note that the description contains a STRING that is formatted as if it were json. This is correct."

Comment: `$xyz = json_encode('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "description_key": "\n"inner_text_key1": "inner_text_value"\n}" }'); echo json_decode($xyz);`

returns just fine.

Comment: Just tried this with the 1st string of your question. Have used your curl code. My environment detected content type json and decoded it. I received the PHP array with the json string on the `description_key` offset. --Works as it is on my side.

Comment: Perhaps you got a problem on the receiving end **OR** try to decode, encode the string before sending it.

Comment: As stated in the post, it works fine from CLI (so not a problem on receiving end), but when I try from php it returns: `failed to parse json message. Illegal unquoted character`. If i remove the \n it works fine. Same result with or without CURLOPT_CRLF set.

Comment: @Bruce I updated my answer|post above. Json decode and encode works.
EDIT: about `CURLOPT_CRLF` - i have the feeling the receiving end is on Windows? (does not matter - just decode, encode and line break is gone. If you NEED the line breaks, then try str_replace `\n` with `\r\n` before sending)